# Активный пункт меню php

Tags: php

Не могу понять как сделать активный пункт меню php

```
   <div id="tabs" class="htabs">
        <?php foreach($customer_group as $group) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $group['name']?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

пробовал сделать проверку

```
<?php if($_GET['customer_group_id'] == $group['customer_group_id'])?>
<?php echo "class='active'"?>
<?php echo $group['name'] ?>
```

Но так что не получилось или это нужно делать через js ?

Comment: `<a <?= $group['customer_group_id'] ==$_GET['customer_group_id'] ? "class='active'" : "" ?> href="<?= $group['customer_group_id'] ?>"><?=  $group['name'] ?></a>`

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
    <?php
      foreach($customer_group as $group) {
         $class = (int)$_GET['customer_group_id'] == (int)$group['customer_group_id']?" class='active'":"";
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $group['customer_group_id']; ?>"<?php echo $class; ?>><?php echo $group['name']?></a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Только убедитесь, что у Вас сравниваемые значения совпадают

Comment: Может что проверка не срабатывает  $_GET['customer_group_id'] мне отдает 1 первый пункт меню, а  $group['customer_group_id'] отдает 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 получается все пункты меню, может быть здесь ошибка ?

Comment: В цикле последовательно сравниваются значения: 1==1, 1==2, 1==3 и т.д. Обновил ответ (так правильнее будет). А еще отобразите сравниваемые значения и посмотрите что с чем сравнивается

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs > a").click(function(){
  $(".active").removeClass("active");//Удаляем класс у прошлого выделенного
  $(this).addClass("active");//добовляем класс
});
```

Соответственно к ссылке добавить class="active".
наверное как-то так.